# Can you delay test kickoff after firefox startup using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to make Selenium wait for 5 seconds after Firefox loads for all my profile changes to get loaded. Currently WebDriver is kicking off the test before the profile changes are made and hence failing. Is there any built in functions in WebDriver to delay test start?

Thanks!

Comment: cant you just put the pause in the java code?

Comment: how are you setting the profile?  Usually you can do that before loading the browser.

Comment: @BevynQ There is no pause function for WebDriver. Farlan: I am setting the profile using the built-in FirefoxProfile object and passing it to the Selenium driver on creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using java after launching the browser simply

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: You could try using an implicit or explicit wait http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp but that's assuming the browser has launched and you're waiting for a specific element.

Comment: Is there anything that I could do using selenium driver capabilities for Firefox. There doesn't seem to be any good documentation on it. Opera has better documentation here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver

Comment: Not that I know of but I do agree that documentation is lacking so I wouldn't completely rule out that there's a better solution out there.